# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje después de un submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario el cual elimina un registro de la base de datos. Los datos del formulario los mando por medio de AJAX y cuando el resultado es positivo, necesito redireccionar a otra página del mismo sitio web y añadir un mensaje (en la página que se redirecciono) de que el registro se ha eliminado correctamente.

¿Cómo podría hacer eso?
Esto es lo que tengo.

```
  $('.form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let e_IDs_FORM = $('.form input[type="hidden"]');
    var url = `${e_HOST}/pepito.php`;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: e_IDs_FORM.serialize(),
      success: function(data)
      {
        if (data['success']) {
          let e_NOTIFICACION = data['RETURN']['NOTIFICACIONES']['SUCCESS'][0];

          setTimeOut(function(){
            window.location.replace(`${e_HOST}/index.php`);
          },4500);
          $('#msg div:first-child').addClass('msg');
          $('#msg .msg').css('background-color','#21610B');
          $('#msg .msg > span').text("Se elimino el sitio.");
          $('#msg').css('display','block');
          $('#msg').fadeOut(4500);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Que error sale o que quieres saber?

Comment: Las otras líneas posteriores a la redirección están de más. Para mostrar el mensaje podría tener una variable `session`  para en el `index` valide el valor de esta variable y si tiene el valor que desea lanza la alerta caso contrario no hará nada.

Comment: @Ivan More Flores No presenta ningún error. Más bien quiero mostrar un mensaje después de hacer el submit y recargar la página.

Comment: El mensaje se abrira en la pantalla actual o en la que sigue?

Comment: @Ivan More Flores En la pantalla que sigue, ahí quiero mostrarla y no se como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de lograr esto, es enviando el mensaje a mostrar en la siguiente página como un parámetro de la URL. Algo asi:

```
$('.form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let e_IDs_FORM = $('.form input[type="hidden"]');
var url = `${e_HOST}/pepito.php`;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: e_IDs_FORM.serialize(),
  success: function(data)
  {
    if (data['success']) {
      const message = data['RETURN']['NOTIFICACIONES']['SUCCESS'][0];
      const encodedMessage = encodeURIComponent(message);
      window.location.replace(`${e_HOST}/index.php?msg=${encodedMessage}`);
    }
  }
});
```

Pero esto es poco elegante, ya que el mensaje aparece en la URL.

---

La forma elegante de lograrlo, es guardar en sesión el mensaje a mostrar, en vez de enviarlo en la respuesta AJAX. Y tras la redirección, en el script de la página de destino, obtener desde sesión el mensaje, y renderizarlo dentro del HTML. Es importante eliminar de la sesión el mensaje, una vez leido, para evitar que si el usuario recarga la página el mensaje se muestre para siempre.

En este caso, se simplifica el JS:

```
$('.form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let e_IDs_FORM = $('.form input[type="hidden"]');
var url = `${e_HOST}/pepito.php`;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: e_IDs_FORM.serialize(),
  success: function(data)
  {
    if (data['success']) {
      window.location.replace(`${e_HOST}/index.php`);
    }
  }
});
```

El concepto de almacenar un mensaje en sesión para mostrarlo una sola vez, se llama `flash session`. Todos los frameworks implementan un mecanismo para conseguirlo, pero se puede realizar manualmente de forma sencilla también.

NOTA: hay que tener en cuenta los casos en que se producen errores. Supongo que para tu ejemplo has eliminado el código de gestión de errores.